# Hibernate Query readOnly DAO

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using the following structure to perform db queries:

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List<String>>() {

    @Override
    public List<String> doInHibernate(Session session) {
        Query query = "select * from whatever";
        query.setReadOnly(true);
        return query.list();
    }
}
```

Some mapping of attributes might occur in the ongoing hibernate session but those tables shouldn't be altered in any way. I've first tried to use evict(object) for those specific entities but readOnly seems like the better way and I'm loading these unmodifiable objects without anything else attached in a separate DAO. I can't touch the hibernate mapping itself, so any changes there aren't an option for me.

Basically my question is:

(1) Does using evict or setting readOnly make any difference in this case?

(2) Is there a neat way to set readOnly(true) for every call in a DAO? I'm afraid that new methods in the future might forget to set the readOnly part and mess up my db.

Comment: answer for your 2nd question : try this . Session.setDefaultReadOnly(true)

Comment: Won't that make all entities in my session read only? I only want to exclude certain entities from being updated.

Comment: Yes it will make all entities to ReadOnly ! Than try this : Session.setReadOnly(Entity object, Read Permission true/false); In your case it should true. I think this should work !

Comment: That seems to be about one specific persistent entity, not the table as a whole, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: In your 2nd question you have mentioned that you want to set readonly for every DAO call. Than every dao call will use some hibernate entities. For such type of issues you should make Session.setDefaultReadOnly(true).

Comment: But if I use another DAO within this session that readOnly property will transfer to it as well, right? I'm thinking about implementing a super class that will set readOnly properties for specific DAO calls only.